# Drawing shapes does not work in graphics2D

Tags: java, swing, graphics, applet, japplet

The below code is to display a triangle in applet.But it does not work for me. If i pass `Graphics g` instead of `Graphics2D g` then it works fine.But i want to know what the mistake i am doing while using `Graphics g`. I am new to java and learning from some online tutorials. So please correct my program and tell me what mistake i am doing.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class Vehicle extends JFrame {

    final int WIDTH = 900;
          int HEIGHT = 650;


    public void init() {

        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }
    public void paint(Graphics2D g) {

 Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
     Dimension d = getSize();
     System.out.println(d);
            int[] yPoints={150,250,250};
            int[] xPoints={200,150,250};


        g2.setColor(Color.green);


        g2.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, 3);
        g2.drawRect(100, 100, 100, 100);

        g2.setColor(Color.red);

        g2.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, 3);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Vehicle v= new Vehicle();
       v.init();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `paint(Graphics g)` is defined in [`java.awt.Component`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29). This is more or less legacy code. However, this API hasn't changed for a long time and is inherited by modern Swing components, such as `JFrame`.

You can't simply change the method signature (in your case to `paint(Graphics2D g)`), you have to live with the signature defined by the API.

So, in your case, the `paint(Graphics2D g)` does not override the API method `paint(Graphics g)`, and thus is not called when updating the `JFrame`. Nothing is painted.

Change your code like this:

```java
----------------%<----------------------

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) { // <-- Change from Graphics2D to Graphics

 Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
     Dimension d = getSize();
     System.out.println(d);
            int[] yPoints={150,250,250};
            int[] xPoints={200,150,250};

---------------->%----------------------
```

Comment: Ok.but what changes i should do? If i use frame instead of Jframe then does it work?

Comment: No, just use `paint(Graphics g)`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a good look at what your program is doing before looking for assistance. (Not scolding you, just trying to help for the future.)

You have `public void paint(Graphics2D g)`, which, as Petersen stated, is not a method in the JFrame class. A good trick to use to check if your methods in swing will do what tutorials say they will do is to put `@Override` above the method. If it errors, it means that method is not in `JFrame` or whatever superclass you have. Otherwise, it is overriding the method.

Additionally, another flag would be the next line: `Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;`
Here you're casting a `Graphics2D` object as a `Graphics2D` object... which should never need to happen.. haha

If you are just getting started with swing and Graphics2D I suggest learning some of the Panels systems and other low-level things like `drawImage` or `drawString`, if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Thank you.I got it. I started learning java just few days back.

Comment: If I have satisfied your question, please mark an answer as accepted so we do not receive duplicate answers and external visitors can get the help they need. Glad I could assist :)

Comment: Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545048/java-calling-repaint-from-another-class-jframe) for information on `JPanel`s - a feature you should start using. Calling `paint()` in the JFrame is not a good practice. You should `add(Component c)` a custom `JPanel` to the `JFrame` and write your graphics code in the `JPanel`'s `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Working with Java2D it often helps to imagine your application as an animation. Imagine that at one point one specific frame(I am talking about animation frames okay) is drawn on the screen. When some event occurs we replace this frame with another frame incorporating the change much like the way cartoons or animation movies are built. How we draw animation frames? How do we switch between frames?

Java API provides a paint(graphics g) method for its components to be drawn. And then to update the same component you really call repaint() which simply calls paint(Graphics g) again and displays any changes on to the screen. This API method has a strict signature that we shall follow. It is paint(Graphics g). But Graphics2D is much like a cool kid on the block that provides more functionality because Graphics was too old(legacy) and not cool anymore. So how do we do this because paint(Graphics g) only accepts Graphics not Graphics2D? Graphics2D is a subclass of Graphics okay.
Protocol is simple,

1. Use the legacy paint(Graphics g) method of every component.
2. Once we have used super.paint(Graphics g) (if needed) ,we can typecast the Graphic object that we were using for legacy purposes to Graphics2D to get enhance functionality.(you have done this step right)

**Problem with your code:**
It is only the signature. Java and the repaint() expect the method to be paint(Graphics g) but you have changed the signature and now the above protocol (or contract) is broken. The idea is to keep the contract(by not changing the signature) and then typecast and override to add extended features. Java is not able to find paint(Graphics g) and so repaint() will not also find paint(Graphics g).