# 2D Game not repainting

Tags: java, jframe, paint, repaint

I checked the other questions and couldn't find one with the same case as me so here's my question.

I am making a 2 player stick fighting game that you can play on the same computer using different keys. Everything's fine but when I try to move the oval on the screen with the keys, it's not moving.

Here's the code for my first class - http://pastebin.com/wA0JXdzr
                      second class - http://pastebin.com/ArByyirt

I think I need to call repaint in my second class in the gameloop, but it's saying that it can't make a static reference to it.

Comment: Using external service for sharing codes is discouraged. Codes should be included in the question directly as text.

Comment: My bad, I'm just terrible with the code blocks, they wouldn't paste correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call a non static method directly from another class which is not legal in java. The paint() method in your first class is the non-static method. You were able to use the variables stickx2 and such because they are static as defined in your first class.

Thus, I suggest you create an object of stickFrame() in the gameLoop class and copy all your code in your stickframe main method and put it in your gameLoop main method. It is highly not recommended that you have two main methods.

Declare a Stick Frame variable below your Serialization ID.

```
StickFrame s;
```

Then instantiate it in your gameLoop constructor

```
s = new StickFrame();
```

Now we need to fix the repaint from another class problem.
To do this we need a method in the gameLoop Class.

```
  public void repaintStickFrame()
  {
      s.repaint();
  }
```

Then call it by

```
s.repaintStickFrame() in your loop.
```

or you can just call

```
s.repaint();//place in loop
```

Heres a link to a question that is similar to yours and has solutions as well

[Calling repaint from another class JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545048/calling-repaint-from-another-class-jframe)

Heres a link that explains how you can call an objects method once you've created one (Like we did above, which allowed us to call the repaint() method from a different class):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html